How to speed up the writing process?
I am the parent of an amazing and brilliant child who is also autistic / ADHD.  They are currently in college at Stanford, majoring in physics and are a first gen college student.
Writing has always been a struggle for my kiddo.  Not the knowledge part or the research part - but the ability to take all the information they have gathered and put into outline form and be able to actually turn it into narrative form for papers.  I personally believe that this is due to the "black and white", "right or wrong" way their brain functions.  With physics (math, science, etc) there is a right answer.  You get to the right answer and you're done.  Writing doesn't work that way, so they get stuck in the mud.
What they write is amazing (and even award-winning), but the amount of time that it takes them to put it all together just isn't working for college classes.  I know there have got to be tools that can help or tutors or something, but I just don't know where to start to help them get the tools they need.
Any guidance, references, referrals... anything would be greatly appreciated.

I would think that a counsellor trained in the specifics of autism etc. would be a better source of answers and finding a solution.  I worry that a general or AI "solution" would provide "answers" that kiddo would find it hard to evaluate, leading them astray. I suggest you seek a solution elsewhere. One solution I'd suggest, however, would be collaboration with those who aren't neurodivergent.

Writing is hard for many students, autism or no, ADHD or no. Universities I have attended had programs specifically for writing help, like a "writing center". I'd highly recommend your child look into writing programs at Stanford  rather than trying to do it all yourself. I would separately look at support specifically for students with autism or ADHD at Stanford: https://studentlearning.stanford.edu/neurodiversity Excellent institutions like Stanford are in part excellent because they have a lot of support programs for students.

Keep in mind that writing in humanities classes that your child will have to take to satisfy general Ed requirements is very different from writing in science (including math) classes. Does your child have trouble with former, or later or both?

With more advanced science the answers are nuanced, there isn't a strictly right answer (even for something as pure as maths). When you talk about research papers, do you mean academic research papers for journals or essays for classes? I suspect part of my confusion is due to the American system being unique with required non-specialist courses, the course I took that was least like physics during my physics undergrad was high performance computing. For general writing: "The sense of style" by pinker might be good, it goes over why we write the way we do, might illuminate assumed knowledge.

On a positive note, some neurodivergent people do well in academia. I know a few of them who are on the spectrum. They have, however, trained themselves to "seem" otherwise. But they have a great ability to focus and concentrate. They don't depend on "tools", however.

Thank you all for taking time and giving me input!
The class is this: GEOLPHYS 219 Planetary Surface Processes Shaping the Landscape of the Solar System
@MoisheKohan - they have completed all their core classes, the ones they're in now are 4th year level courses that are very specific to their degree.  I believe they call it a Science Research Paper. (?)

@BryanKrause - THANKS!  I will definitely get that information to them.  They are set up with OEA (I'm still surprised they can't give more guidance).  I think the writing center would be an amazing option!

Has your child been diagnosed by a clinician?

@Buffy: there may be a survivorship bias with your neurodivergent collaboration partners. I have to say that I'm not aware of particular tools as being actually very helpful with autism. (Except maybe things like lowering monitor contrast - which you may not count as tool. But I'd be happy to be corrected.) But assuming that no such tools are  widely used (since a long time), then of course only neurodivergent researchers who managed to cope without tools throughout their studies and professional life can be your collaborators. If there were others, they likely (and silently) dropped out: IIRC

the proportion of autists with normal or high intelligence that have (at least over here in Germany) an academic degree is higher than the corresponding proportion of the general population. Nevertheless, only 15 % are in full-time jobs. While STEM in academia may be more accommodating or suitable than other fields or industry, my guesstimate would still be that quite some did drop out.

Did you effectively disclose your child's identity and personal medical information on SE or did you use a pseudonym? ... and no, don't answer that question here.

First of all, I am a mathematician, not a physicist. However, some of the issues you are describing are common to both disciplines. The reality is that nobody (to the best of my knowledge) teaches how to write research papers or, more precisely, given the situation that you described, survey papers. The way it is usually done is that students are given several papers to read; some of these are original research papers, some are survey papers. Then students are expected to imitate the general structure that they see in the written materials to produce their own work. These materials are typically given to students by their instructors (in the case when it is a written assignment in a class) or advisors (in the case of a Master or PhD thesis). Make sure your child has access to several such papers. If not, your child should contact the instructor/advisor and ask for the materials. This might not be enough, but that's a start. If these samples are not enough, look at the list of references in the given materials and make sure your child looks at the review papers in that list. (It take some skill to identify which are review papers and which are original research articles.) The way I usually do it in the classes I teach (but I mke such assignments only in graduate classes) is to tell students that I expect them to write in their own words a description of the results in the assigned papers; I tell them the expected length of the work (about 2 pages). I also tell students to come to my office hours to discuss these assignments in case something is unclear.
Hope, it helps.

My understanding of in particular autism is that the imitation part may not work for them as is works for other students. Thus, going through papers of the kind and style that is requested is IMHO worth trying, but I wouldn't put too high expectations on it working.

First of all, your child sounds truly inspirational - to have autism/ADHD is challenging at university, so to also be a first generation student to go to university, and to go to one of the top in the whole World is an amazing achievement.
From the point of view as a mathematician, writing is something which the majority of early research mathematicians struggle with. One could speculate why - I suspect that it is partly to do with transitioning over from writing solutions and ideas for only yourself, to writing as a form of communication to others. It's a learning process which never stops, and we hope improves throughout our lifetime. Please take my suggestions with a pinch of salt as these are tips which work for me, but your child will need to find what works for them.
My first suggestion is to read physics which is well-written. For example, I often look to who are considered the greatest communicators of maths, like Milnor. For physics, I suggest Paul Dirac's writing. Whilst I haven't read all of his work, I read his paper on singularities in the electromagnetic field which I consider a great piece of scientific communication. It gave a sense of Dirac teaching you and guiding you through each step to get you on the same page as him. Search for various other examples and see what can be learnt. Stephen King once said 'If you don't have time to read, you don't have time to write' which seems applicable to writing in general.
Second, I strongly recommend breaking writing up into sections. For example, when I have written a research paper or dissertation, I don't sit down and write it out in one go. It usually involves several small problem which one works on and then aims to put it together into a piece of writing at the end. When I consider these individual problems, I try to flesh out my writing even at this stage. Don't just write workings, explain the steps. This means that when it comes to writing up into a cohesive piece, it will be far easier.
Third, if time constraints is an issue, then having a good timetable is very important. It makes a task which seems overwhelming much more doable. For example, if you have a piece of writing due in a fortnight, then split this up into small daily tasks, leaving the final few for reviewing and refining.
Also, don't be afraid to reach out to the university. My experience is that they understand scientific writing is hard, and have specialist support on hand to help with this. For example, I have seen universities before where literature students proofread science dissertations, not to check the content, but to check the readability. Plus, if enough people share that scientific writing is something they are struggling with, the university may have sufficient numbers to organise some sort of workshop.
And importantly, here are some resources which are much more knowledgable than myself:

A useful Stack Exchange post: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27675/how-to-write-a-paper-in-physics

An article by N. David Mermin at Cornell: http://mermin.lassp.cornell.edu/KnightLecture.html

A paper by Igor Pac with tips on writing mathematics papers from a modern perspective: https://www.math.ucla.edu/~pak/papers/how-to-write1.pdf

Terrance Tao's blog post on writing, which has lots of links to other resourcesL https://terrytao.wordpress.com/advice-on-writing-papers/



These are all good suggestions as to how to write better, but the question is about writing faster.

@Arno Thank you for the comment, you're right I should have targeted my suggestions to be more about writing faster. To me, however, if I can write well and get a feel for what scientific writing is, then it speeds up my writing process because I'm not having to stop and start so much. But your feedback is well taken.

THANK YOU so much!!!!

Other answers have explained that the writing part is hard for almost every (STEM) student.
However, my understanding of autism suggest that there are several points that may need to be considered separately from a high level of the usual struggles.
General considerations
For the what-can-be-done parts I assume that kiddo has a proper medical diagnosis which is (or can be) registered with either the exam office or a disability office of the university (the exam office should be able to guide kiddo wherever else they need to go).
Still, it is up to kiddo to decide whether they want to communicate their condition at all. Doing so certainly has drawbacks as well, and a good overall strategy will depend on details that should not be written publicly in the internet.

Lots of thoughts I have require negotiating. While this likely poses difficulties in itself related to the autism (and possibly also the ADHD), I'd say the ability to negotiate appropriate working conditions is an even far more important professional skill for them than scientific writing.

Talk to the exam and/or disability office of the university.
Autism + ADHD is not a rare condition. AFAIK, ADHD has a prevalence in the order of magnitude of 1 in 10, autism 1 in 100 in the general population. Also they frequently co-occur (1 in 3 people on the autism spectrum also have ADHD). This means that exam/disability offices should have experience even with the particular combination of autism + ADHD. This makes them a very valuable source of information about what has helped others (or also what did not work), and of course they know what are acceptable accommodations and what would constitute an unfair advantage.

Find out exactly what knowledge and abilities are to be graded.
I suspect that the ability to wrote a scientific essay paper is part of these, but there may be sufficient other goals which are much less problematic for kiddo: subject knowledge, being able to apply the subject knowledge to new problems, being able to learn a new research topic on their own from a literature search, ....
It also may turn out that the paper-writing in itself does not rank that high in the instructors teaching goals and that it is for them mainly a convenient way of evaluation.
Once this is known, it may become possible to negotiate for accommodations that allow a fair evaluation of the relevant professional abilities. E.g., an oral exam may evaluate all points except the writing part. (As difficult as oral communication may be, it has the important advantage that misunderstandings and ambiguities may be spotted and corrected during the exam, either by kiddo or the examiner.)
It may also be possible with the help of the exam/disability office to decide that kiddo goes for a particular scientific writing course with grading on this (and thus avoid a statement that they were exempted from essay writing on their final degree), but for the scientific subject courses some form of evaluation is chosen that is more suitable.


ADHD
I have less knowledge about ADHD than about autism. That being said, I'd expect the consequence of the ADHD to be mainly inability to concentrate over sufficiently long times on a given (and uninteresting) task. Possible accommodations to ask/negotiate for may be:

Asking for a topic that is inherently interesting for kiddo. Including suggesting topics to the instructor so they can decide which would be acceptable for the course.
Getting more time, which is also an accommodation in line with the autistic needs.
There may be other accommodations such as working through the topic with a tutor who keeps kiddo from straying away with their thoughts but does not interfere with the topic-related output kiddo produces.

The first one may be negotiated with the instructor without involving exam or disability office. The latter 2 are a level of accommodation that an instructor likely cannot agree on on their own, but a disability office may decide that this is appropriate.
Specific points related to autism

Literal* understanding of language is typical for autistic people. If the task is not very precisely and unambiguously worded and explained, kiddo may spend lots of time trying to guess (i.e., thinking what may be meant and evaluating likelihood for each possibility), and maybe even writing the essay/paper to cover many possibilities.
However, IMHO asking for precise, clear and unambiguous task statement is not an accommodation since it is also better for the neurotypical students. But their guesses of what is meant are likely closer to what the instructor had in mind.

Learning from example/do-as-I-do without spelled-out explanations may not work for autistic people.
(As others have noted, it is hard also for neurotypical students. But for them it is doable, while it may not be possible for autistic students. See next point for reasons.)

I think it is worth while to put a limited amount of time and effort into getting a selection of good example papers, including good answer texts/essays/papers from previous years: kiddo may ask the instructor whether this is acceptable considering the course rules, and if so, whether instructor could please put them into contact with students who handed in very well-done solutions to previous survey topics. (Where I am, a new list of current topics to do the literature search and essay paper on is handed out every year.)

If that doesn't turn out to help, ask for specific explanations of how exactly to write. (I'm only medium optimistic that this will produce a useable result, but it is certainly worth trying.)
Personally, I think a reputable tertiary level education institution should be able to explain scientific writing in an understandable fashion. (Lately I've noticed improvements in courses about scientific writing explaining working techniques and tools that one may use.)

Discuss with instructor and exam/disability office what accommodations are appropriate. E.g.,

A literature search yielding a literature list may be graded separately from the essay paper writing part.
Result presentation format may be adapted. E.g. putting the results into a table with systematic evaluation and/or bullet point lists rather than an essay-style text may be acceptable. (If kiddo can summarize and evaluate each paper for a set of characteristics but has difficulties expressing the knowledge in sentences.)
Or a review that gives a very detailed, comprehensive and systematic compilation of the literature. (There are scientific review papers in such style)




Focus on details: Autistic people often take in huge amounts of detail, but may not be able to detect the underlying high-level structure. (My mental model is: detecting low or mid-level structure so strongly that this masks higher level structure)
I think the saying "not to see the forest for the trees" is a good description, in a literal way.
For people without this trait (instructor), this may be such a strange notion that they cannot even imagine how this would be.
In this sense, this particular trait of autism may cause a dis-ability (again, literally: lack of ability) to fulfil a "summarize knowledge gathered from the survey" task in the curriculum.
If this happens to be the main problem, it unfortunately means that the autism interferes with a very central professional ability required in STEM. Which does not mean that kiddo cannot find a professional niche where they excel. But it does mean that the course likely grades something that kiddo cannot deliver. Getting accommodation will need to involve the exam/disability office.

Focus on details together with what OP describes as black/white thinking: There may be a related, but different and lesser problem: Inability to produce rough or approximate summaries. If something is not exactly and precisely correct, it is strictly speaking not correct. In consequence, it may be difficult to express (write, say, state) it. There may be a feeling of writing falsehoods for sentences that would perfectly satisfy the correctness requirements of the instructor.
For kiddo:

Neurotypical teachers may work in a way that they omit spelling out approximations as such. When meeting statements that are false because some rare contradicting special cases exist, check whether an approximation is meant.
In addition, neurotypical teachers may expect summaries that make such approximations. This can be hard to do in itself (previous point). But if a statement is false because of a small number of contradictory findings, perfectly true and precise statements are possible: e.g., most of the findings are that ..., while a few contradict. Or: 17 out of 18 papers [Lit1 - Lit17] found that .... [Lit18] instead found .... Such statements are fine for a scientific essay.


Time requirements:  Both autism and ADHD can mean that kiddo will require more time than other students. (For the autism-related part, this additional time will also lead to vastly more detail knowledge than faster students will have.)  Giving more time to complete tasks is a common accommodation which the exam/disability office (or the instructor) can grant.
Studying part time, i.e., taking fewer courses than usual at a time may be something that kiddo can do without the need of anyone knowing their condition.



What they write is amazing (and even award-winning)

If one needs to surpass a given threshold (= passing the course), the aim is threshold + safety margin related to uncertainty. Now if the uncertainty is huge, predictably passing requires to aim very high.
Autism may cause an inability to judge what the expectation is, so much larger uncertainty than neurotypical students experience. Plus, the autism may cause an increased need for predictability. Which would call for even larger safety margin.
Kiddo lowering their standard (as some other answer suggests) may thus not be a feasible option.
OTOH, some of the writing techniques I've met in a scientific writing course deliberately aim at a rough draft which is completed before parts or sentences are refined in several rounds. If this is a feasible working technique for kiddo, a possible accommodation would be to show the intermediate stages either to the instructor or to a tutor, and stop and hand in as soon as they say it is fine.

I'm not sure whether producing the correct style of writing is a particular problem related to autism. (I'd expect it to be less problematic than the other points once the rules for the desired scientific style are known.)
But here are some bits and pieces of advise I've gathered over time. Fortunately, they suggest that there are rules that one can follow, and the actual rules may even be nice for autistic people (compared to the rules of literary writing): The essay-writing training I had was - like for all my peers - in language/literature courses in school, plus the training one gets from applying this in social science subjects. (I once had a German teacher who said that handing in 2 pages of answer when everyone else produces 8 - 15 pages is actually better if those 2 pages contain the same information.) Natural science in school asked questions where at most putting facts and logics into sentences was required. When I wrote my first papers, my prof taught me: we're in science here, not in literature. Plus we expect that for the readers (like for us), English not to be their native language. Thus, stick to short, easy, precise sentences. Do not use synonyms but stick to one term and use it in an exact and precise fashion. Also spell out this definition. (My native language favours long sentences. Heavy switching between synonym use is taught as a must in school.)

Generative AI: although its use is typically forbidden in study context, the exam/disability office could allow also this as accommodation if they think it appropriate.
That being said, I'm unsure whether it would help: while I could e.g. imagine a very long and detailed draft text by kiddo could be AI summarized into something of a suitable length for handing in, I'd also expect that the result is distastefully blah-blah and imprecise to an autistic mind.
(I expect logics to be less of a problem, since I expect an autistic user to closely stick to the requirement of personally verifying the correctness of the generated text, and an autistic physics student to spot any logical flaws immediately).



Side note about strategical decisions: I've been in a discussion lately at my professional society where we were thinking about how to deal with one's own strengths and weaknesses.
We compared focusing effort on improving the strengths to reach excellence (we called it "American-style") to focusing effort on getting rid of weaknesses ("German-style"). Both are useful, and sometimes weaknesses are so important that something needs to be done for sheer survival. Kiddo likely has put quite some effort into such topics. Otherwise, putting effort into things that one can do well is very rewarding, both mentally/psychologically and in terms of what can be achieved. It is IMHO important not to forget this.
What can and IMHO should be done as well is to look which specializations/niches exist in the professional world that suit well to one's abilities.
People on this SX tend to emphasize how important paper writing is - which is true for their daily work in academia. But niches and positions requiring more thinking and less from-scratch-writing than others do exist. So do niches where the importance less the sheer amount of output, but its precision and correctness.
While predictions are difficult, in particular about the future, I expect that during kiddo's professional life, generative AI tools will be available that are actually helpful at transforming thoughts as expressed natively by an autist into neurotypical scientific language (and the other way round as well). So it may be totally worth while to get through strenuous study requirements now, and later use tools that make every-day work easier.

* unfortunately, "literally" is sometimes used to refer to a figurative meaning (As in "literatlly speaking, ..." where ... is meant in a figurative way).
I'd therefore like to clarify: I use literally exclusively refering to the direct meaning of the wording. That is, as the opposite of figuratively.

For someone in the STEM fields, one mental tip I have run across for dealing with the forest for trees problem: Look to abstraction and modeling. Is Newtonian physics wrong because it doesn't have the detail of Einsteinian relativity? Is basic arithmetic inferior to module theory? Having this conversation and exploring the idea that you can have models at multiple layers, that are 'good enough for the context'. Explicitly approximate rather than implicitly approximate maybe an acceptable compromise rather than trying to cover all the detail.

Also understand this may require a multistage process of building the mid level structure and then the high level from that. Something which unfortunately takes a lot more time and mental energy and is more vulnerable to being disrupted by learning about a subtle misunderstanding.

Oh my heck - thank you ALL so much!!!  I can't tell you how much I appreciate the information.

There is no way, I'm afraid, to speed up the writing process and still have high quality. It is a hard task.
To obtain high quality of output, for many people, maybe most at the early stages, is to get feedback on whatever you write. It is astonishingly difficult to evaluate your own work. Even proofreading for your own spelling errors is very hard. The problem is that the eyes see what you think you wrote on the page, not what you did write, so you skip over fairly obvious errors. Even "sophisticated" spell checkers can mislead you when they insert the wrong word.
For some who are neurodivergent it may be even more difficult to obtain that feedback, as some have communication issues, making it hard to find those willing and able to provide adequate feedback. Stanford might actually be a good place to find support for that.
There is also the issue, for a student, that obtaining feedback from other students might be against the rules. However, if a professor is made aware of the issues they might be able to provide some assistance. One option is to have a grad student give your kiddo feedback on their writing.
Like any skill, writing takes practice. In a complex field, it isn't a natural skill for most. That means repetition and feedback, perhaps for a long while, until it begins to feel natural.
I mentioned that I have friends (and co-authors) who are somewhat neurodivergent, but have succeeded (beyond myself, actually). One of them has his doctorate from Stanford. He is still occasionally painful to communicate with, but he does excellent and widely regarded work. He also suffered some setbacks along the way but overcame them with hard work. He is a marvelous writer.
And, a warning: having "tools" isn't going to ease the task if excellence is the goal. What "tools" will make you a world-class tennis player? The best tool is probably a coach who gives feedback on your obsessive practice.
A visitor to the city asks a native New Yorker "How do I get to Carnegie Hall". The answer is and has always been: "Practice, practice, practice."

Since comments often disappear, let me repeat Bryan Krause's link to Stanford's support: https://studentlearning.stanford.edu/neurodiversity

One thing that may be worthwhile for someone with autism: having someone who can help understand what feedback means and how to ask for it. This is where an autistic counsellor could help. Coaching given by neurotypicals isn't always easy to interpret by those on the spectrum,  and is something that may need support in its own right.

+1 for general acknowledgement that writing is hard and that practice helps - with the autism focused addition to get relevant required tutoring/feedback (and the Stanford link). Nevertheless, I'd like to disagree on the tools. On the one hand, appropriate use of tools is IMHO part of mastering one's profession. On the other hand, if there exist tools that help to overcome the specific autistic disabilities IMHO they should be used. Like a legasthenic student should use a spell-checker, someone with ADHD should take their medication, use alarm-clock and automatic calendar reminders, etc.

Producing excellent academic writing quickly just isn't a realistic goal for almost anyone. Experience can help getting faster, but that's not really applicable here. I suspect that what your child needs to do is to lower their standards for college coursework and just produce good enough stuff. The first big hurdle towards that probably is to give themselves permission to skip their own quality control process.
As far as writing tools are concerned, we've got spell checkers (very useful, can probably taken for granted), grammar/style checkers and generative AI tools. Grammar/style checkers can be useful for someone struggling with low-level language stuff, in particular if they are still learning the language they write in. I don't think they can do much to speed up writing for someone who isn't struggling with these things. Generative AI can massively speed up writing, but on the one hand is typically forbidden in a university context, and on the other hand tends to produce rather mediocre results. Gen AI output tends to look good at a first glance, but just lacks coherent logical structures.

Hmmm. Lower standards??

@Buffy Yes, lower standards. We are talking about coursework here.

Let me disagree, then.

I'm not sure the traits that cause autistic writing to be slow but meticulous allow them to lower the standard in the way appear to think. But it is certainly worth considering.
